# dropdown menu in bootstrap modal not showing

Tags: javascript, php, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap 4 and my select is not working. The dropdown in the modal doesn't show up.

Heres my code:

```
<div class="div-input-text" data-validate="xyz"> 
     <select class="selectpicker input-text" id="xyz-profile" required title="" style="min-height: 40px;" name="xyz" data-live-search="true">
          <option selected disabled hidden value=""></option>
          <option value="1">banana</option>
     </select>
     <span class="input-placeholder" data-placeholder="xyz"></span>
</div>
```

In javascript after openening the modal I am doing:

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
```

Do you have any hints?

In the same file, but just not the modal, it works fine

Comment: what about you instantiate it before the action of opening the modal?